# How do I determine the big O for my nested for loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, computation-theory

I have a nested for loop. I am aware that a nested for loop is of O(n2). I have some code that runs in the for loops, but it is conditional, as it only runs if conditions are met. Is that to be factored into the big O? Or is it so small compared the scaling of O(n2) that it is meaningless?

Comment: At the very least, you will have to check the condition O(n^2) times, so the code complexity is at least O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

It does not matters whether your meets the conditions.If you are thinking about big O notation then you should consider the worst case scenario where your code will meet all conditions and execute it.

below is the link that might help you,

https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/